# Different possible nestings of Buffered reader and InputStreams

Tags: java, bufferedreader, fileinputstream, bufferedinputstream

Let's say that I want to read a file (encoded in some charset) on text level, not on byte level. So I need a `Reader` class.

Let's also say that I want the reading to be buffered. I see at least three ways to do this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));
    BufferedReader r2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("foo.txt")));
    InputStreamReader r3 = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("foo.txt")));
}
```

r1 and r2 are pretty much the same, since `FileReader` inherits from `InputStreamReader` and practically puts an `InputStream` in it's base class. Buffering in that case will be done at character level, after the bytes are decoded to text.

But the third case is somewhat different, as the buffering happens between the byte reading and the decoding to text. Buffering happens before the bytes are decoded to text.

Mu question is, is there any important difference, any gotchas between these cases? Is there an edge case where one option will be better than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of [`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html):

```
public class FileReader extends InputStreamReader {
    public FileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    }
}
```

So you see, your first two lines result in exactly the same chain.

Third option is no so good for performance. `InputStreamReader` has to do character encoding conversion from `byte` stream to `char` stream, which is slow on a byte-by-byte level, but faster in blocks.

See javadoc of [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html):

> Each invocation of one of an InputStreamReader's read() methods may cause one or more bytes to be read from the underlying byte-input stream. To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation.
>
> **For top efficiency, consider wrapping an InputStreamReader within a BufferedReader.** For example:
>
> ```
> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
> ```

Go with options 1. It's shorter than option 2 and does exactly the same thing, and option 3 is not a good choice.